# How to run a simple Hello World node js application in Ubuntu LXC container?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, lxc, linux-containers

I have a nodejs application - express app.

My use case here is I need to run the node js application inside a LXC container in  ubuntu.

I need to understand how a simple nodejs app works in a container so that I can move onto porting my express app.

So far I have created an LXC container and installed node js in the container. I have also installed some node modules like express, ws inside the container.

Now, I am kind of stuck. Where do I put my source code inside the container? How do I run it?

Is there any resources I can follow to run a nodejs app inside LXC?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  What problems did you run into?  For those problems, what do you run, what happens, and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: +1 for including what you tried on a high level, but I more mean what _commands have you run_, what is their output, and what do you consider expected output?